# Testing quality of sustained call quality to a Public number

Tags: voip, telephony, phone, telephone

While migrating from an old Avaya to Skype for Business (on-prem), I have been asked a few questions about call duration and call quality during maintenance. Questions stem from unclear answers from the team that manages the firewalls about how it could manage longer conference calls (2+ hours). The concern with maintenance is if we have to migrate the Skype (virtual) servers to a new host, what downtime we could expect.

I am looking for numbers which I can call to both generate traffic and to confirm call quality. I found one [list](http://oldphoneguy.net/test_numbers.htm), but several of the numbers disconnect after about 10 minutes, have large breaks in audio, or in at least one case a number now associated with a business.

I use to use the Time Voice Announcer, Washington, DC - +1-202-762-1401 but it appears to disconnect between 5 and 15 minutes, and has frequent pauses in audio. Any test numbers you use, and why?

Comment: Started using +1-760-733-9969 "Mojave Phone Booth"as well. It is now a conference line with some decent hold music.